# Only allow the user that created the post to edit, update or delete the post with Devise

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Currently I have hid the buttons to the users on the posts that they haven't created. How can I prevent them from being able to update, edit or delete the post in the `posts_controller`? I have tried using `if @post.user == current_user` around the edit, update and delete methods but that just returns a stack trace:

```
Missing template posts/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/user1/workspace/webapp/app/views" * "/Users/user1/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views"
```

How can I get the user that is trying to edit the post and if he isn't the owner prevent him from editing, updating or deleting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to have a template for unauthorized access or you can redirect to a url `if @post.user == current_user`. Like below

```
 if @post.user == current_user
    flash.now[:error] = 'unauthorized access!'
    redirect_to posts_path
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do you mean if the user who created the post isn't the current user? Not if the poster is the current user?

Comment: yes it may be `if @post.user != current_user`, so any user apart from poster will be getting unauthorized access message.

Comment: At a more abstract level, devise authenticates the user but does not deal with the user authorisation. If you don't want to implement authorization yourself you should look into gems like [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) or [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)